# How to install a Ethereum Classic Geth Client?

Tags: go-ethereum, ethereum-classic, ubuntu, installation

I was trying to install Go-Ethereum Classic in Ubuntu(VM) using the following guide 
     https://github.com/ethereumproject/go-ethereum
I followed the steps as per the guide and all went fine till

```
$ go get -v github.com/ethereumproject/go-ethereum/...
```

the next command for installing Geth seems not working. while executing the command cursor blinked for a second and exits from execution.
 I checked the installation  by a geth command 'help' and it returns

```
geth: command not found
```

[image]

I also tried installation using make and it also ended up in error 
[image]

1. How to solve this issue?
2. Is there any reliable source rather than https://github.com/ethereumproject/go-ethereum for the installation instructions of ethereum classic node?

Comment: have you tried this command (inside `~/go/bin` )`./geth`?

Comment: it's working:), but as per the instruction it should have worked with geth @Зелёный

Comment: what is the error with the actual instructions?

Comment: There is no error with actual instruction, with instruction suppose to have `GOPATH` in the `PATH` variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need add `GOPATH` to your `PATH` variable or use full path command `./HERE_IS_PATH_TO_YOUR_GO_BIN/geth`.